# latitude and longitude always return 0.0 when using lastKnownLocation

Tags: java, android, google-api, android-gps, runtime-permissions

I just got the permissions handled through the library Let, but I still can't get a longitude and latitude in my android app.  I'm using a service called GPS_Service.java.  Also I'm not 100% sure my permissions aren't the issue.  The call to the google API in GPS_Service still is underlined with the warning that it requires permissions which might be rejected.  Is that supposed to go away even with third party libraries?  Would this still be an issue because on my device the app has location permissions enabled?

here is my main activity:

```
package com.example.paxie.stormy.ui;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.canelmas.let.AskPermission;
import com.canelmas.let.DeniedPermission;
import com.canelmas.let.Let;
import com.canelmas.let.RuntimePermissionListener;
import com.canelmas.let.RuntimePermissionRequest;
import com.example.paxie.stormy.GPS_Service;
import com.example.paxie.stormy.R;
import com.example.paxie.stormy.weather.Current;
import com.example.paxie.stormy.weather.Day;
import com.example.paxie.stormy.weather.Forecast;
import com.example.paxie.stormy.weather.Hour;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Call;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Callback;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RuntimePermissionListener {

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String DAILY_FORECAST = "DAILY_FORECAST";
    public static final String HOURLY_FORECAST = "HOURLY_FORECAST";
    private Forecast mForecast;
    private double mLatitude;
    private double mLongitude;
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
    private Location location; // location
    private double latitude; // latitude
    private double longitude; // longitude
    private Context mContext;

    @BindView(R.id.timeLabel)
    TextView mTimeLabel;
    @BindView(R.id.temperatureLabel)
    TextView mTemperatureLabel;
    @BindView(R.id.humidityValue)
    TextView mHumidityValue;
    @BindView(R.id.precipValue)
    TextView mPrecipValue;
    @BindView(R.id.summaryLabel)
    TextView mSummaryLabel;
    @BindView(R.id.iconImageView)
    ImageView mIconImageView;
    @BindView(R.id.refreshImageView)
    ImageView mRefreshImageView;
    @BindView(R.id.progressBar)
    ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    @BindView(R.id.locationLabel)
    TextView mLocationlabel;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Let.handle(this, requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);


        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        mRefreshImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getForecast();
            }
        });


        getForecast();
        Log.d(TAG, "Main UI code is running!");
    }

    private void getForecast() {
        checkGPS();
        String apiKey = "1621390f8c36997cb1904914b726df52";
        String forecastUrl = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/" + apiKey +
                "/" + mLatitude + "," + mLongitude;

        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            toggleRefresh();

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(forecastUrl)
                    .build();

            Call call = client.newCall(request);
            call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            toggleRefresh();
                        }
                    });
                    alertUserAboutError();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            toggleRefresh();
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        String jsonData = response.body().string();
                        Log.v(TAG, jsonData);
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            mForecast = parseForecastDetails(jsonData);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    updateDisplay();
                                }
                            });

                        } else {
                            alertUserAboutError();

                        }
                    } catch (IOException e)

                    {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Network is currently unavailable!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    private void toggleRefresh() {
        if (mProgressBar.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mRefreshImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mRefreshImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private void updateDisplay() {
        mLocationlabel.setText(mLatitude + " " + mLongitude);
        Current current = mForecast.getCurrent();
        mTemperatureLabel.setText(current.getTemperature() + "");
        mTimeLabel.setText("At " + current.getFormattedTime() + " it will be:");
        mHumidityValue.setText(current.getHumidity() + "");
        mPrecipValue.setText(current.getPrecipChance() + "%");
        mSummaryLabel.setText(current.getSummary());
        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, current.getIconId());
        mIconImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }

    private Forecast parseForecastDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        Forecast forecast = new Forecast();
        forecast.setCurrent(getCurrentDetails(jsonData));
        forecast.setHourlyForecast(getHourlyForecast(jsonData));
        forecast.setDailyForecast(getDailyForecast(jsonData));

        return forecast;

    }

    private Day[] getDailyForecast(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");
        JSONObject daily = forecast.getJSONObject("daily");
        JSONArray data = daily.getJSONArray("data");

        Day[] days = new Day[data.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonDay = data.getJSONObject(i);
            Day day = new Day();

            day.setSummary(jsonDay.getString("summary"));
            day.setIcon(jsonDay.getString("icon"));
            day.setTemperatureMax(jsonDay.getDouble("temperatureMax"));
            day.setTime(jsonDay.getLong("time"));
            day.setTimeZone(timezone);

            days[i] = day;

        }
        return days;
    }

    private Hour[] getHourlyForecast(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");
        JSONObject hourly = forecast.getJSONObject("hourly");
        JSONArray data = hourly.getJSONArray("data");

        Hour[] hours = new Hour[data.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonHour = data.getJSONObject(i);
            Hour hour = new Hour();
            hour.setSummary(jsonHour.getString("summary"));
            hour.setTemperature(jsonHour.getDouble("temperature"));
            hour.setIcon(jsonHour.getString("icon"));
            hour.setTime(jsonHour.getLong("time"));
            hour.setTimeZone(timezone);

            hours[i] = hour;

        }
        return hours;
    }

    private Current getCurrentDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");
        Log.i(TAG, "From JSON:  " + timezone);

        JSONObject currently = forecast.getJSONObject("currently");
        Current current = new Current();
        current.setHumidity(currently.getDouble("humidity"));
        current.setTime(currently.getLong("time"));
        current.setIcon(currently.getString("icon"));
        current.setPrecipChance(currently.getDouble("precipProbability"));
        current.setSummary(currently.getString("summary"));
        current.setTemperature(currently.getDouble("temperature"));
        current.setTimeZone(timezone);

        Log.d(TAG, current.getFormattedTime());

        return current;
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isAvailable = false;
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            isAvailable = true;
        }
        return isAvailable;
    }


    private void alertUserAboutError() {
        AlertDialogFragment dialog = new AlertDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "error_dialog");
    }


    @OnClick(R.id.dailyButton)
    public void startDailyActivity(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DailyForecastActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(DAILY_FORECAST, mForecast.getDailyForecast());
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    @OnClick(R.id.hourlyButton)
    public void startHourlyActivity(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HourlyForecastActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(HOURLY_FORECAST, mForecast.getHourlyForecast());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
@AskPermission({Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION})
    private void checkGPS() {
        GPS_Service gps_service = new GPS_Service(this);
        gps_service.getLocation();
        mLatitude = gps_service.getLatitude();
        mLongitude = gps_service.getLongitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPermissionRationale(List<String> permissionList, RuntimePermissionRequest permissionRequest) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionDenied(List<DeniedPermission> deniedPermissionList) {
    }
}
```

And here is my GPS_Service.java:

```
package com.example.paxie.stormy;

import android.*;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.canelmas.let.AskPermission;
import com.canelmas.let.DeniedPermission;
import com.canelmas.let.Let;
import com.canelmas.let.RuntimePermissionListener;
import com.canelmas.let.RuntimePermissionRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by paxie on 10/27/16.
 */

public class GPS_Service extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private Location location; // location
    private double latitude; // latitude
    private double longitude; // longitude
    private GoogleApiClient mGAC;
    private Context mContext;
    public static final String TAG = "GPSresource";
    private static final int RC_GPS_PERMS = 124;
    public String[] perm = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

    public GPS_Service(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        try {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGAC.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }



    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGAC = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }


    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     */
    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    public void getLocation() {
        location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGAC);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case enable your GPS and go to google maps and hit the location button, wait until google maps locate u and then go back and test in ur app. This should work because if u are using the first time ur phone without never been conected to GPS it gives u that problem

Answer (score 0):

It is looking for specifically "LastKnownLocation", I had this issue as well. Move about 3 meters and try again. If there is no 'last known location' then it sends a null value.

What I did was set a few if statements for my application. If the GPS Provider was spitting out null values, then use the Network Provider location coordinates, and if that was spitting out null values then I just displayed a message saying "To Wait" or "Try again later". Eventually your GPS Provider will pick up location values after it has been activated for a while.

```
     newLoc = _locationManager.GetLastKnownLocation(_locationProvider);
        if (newLoc != null)
        {
            _latitudeUser = newLoc.Latitude;
            _longitudeUser = newLoc.Longitude;
            _locationText.Text = string.Format("{0:f6},{1:f6}", newLoc.Latitude, newLoc.Longitude);
        }
        else
        {
            _locationProvider = LocationManager.NetworkProvider;
            newLoc = _locationManager.GetLastKnownLocation(_locationProvider);
            if (newLoc != null)
            {
                _latitudeUser = newLoc.Latitude;
                _longitudeUser = newLoc.Longitude;
                _locationText.Text = string.Format("{0:f6},{1:f6}", newLoc.Latitude, newLoc.Longitude);
            }
            else
            {
                _locationText.Text = string.Format("We currently cannot determine your location, please try again later.");
            }
```

Comment: It looks like you're using a different method than me for getting location at all.  I'm not using LocationManager as I thought that was incompatible with using the google location api.

Comment: location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGAC);

is what I'm using